# Setting the boolean in a for loop using firestore is only applying to one object in the list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore, boolean

Using android studio. Written in java. Using firebase.
I have an ArrayList of objects that have a boolean variable.

In firestore i have multiple documents in a collection that have userid and an objectid
I successfully query the documents for any with the firebase user and the objects id. 
I then proceed to set the boolean of each object within the ArrayList to true although the boolean is only applying to the object with equal to the final returned document.
When debugging the objects do get set to true they then all but the last revert to false?
Could someone explain why my boolean is acting this way?

```
MyObject Class;

private boolean giftBagged;

public boolean getObjectBagged() { return objectBagged; }
public void setObjectBagged(boolean objectBagged) { this.objectBagged = 
objectBagged; }
```

Within my main activity. I initialise my ArrayList elsewhere in this class. It is filled with a number of my objects.

```
  database.collection("UserObjectCollection")
                .whereEqualTo("userID", firebaseUser)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
                                    MyObject obj = objectList.get(i);
                                    if (obj.getDocID() == document.getLong("objID").intValue()) {
                                        obj.setObjectBagged(true);
                                    } else {
                                        obj.setObjectBagged(false);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            mcb.onSuccess();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

No error messages.
Debugged and they do get set to true but all revert to false except the last one iterated, when the list is used elsewhere.

If anymore information is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your looping within a loop.  You're not handling the condition to indicate that you've found the value, so lets say that you're at element 5 of 10 and it matches element 7 of 10 in the other array.  It will keep looping, so the next time through the loop, it will reset it to false because element 8 of 10 doesn't match.

It would be better set all of your objectBagged to false (default it in object creation?) , then remove the "else" condition of your loop and only set it to true if it's found.

You could also add a condition to your if test for the docID that would also prevent it from going back to "false" if it was set to "true" in a previous pass.

There are more ways, but those two are fairly straightforward.

Comment: YEESSSS!!! I knew it was to do with loop. I did set default to false in my object last night but did not remove the else statement. I have now removed the else and it works!! Thank you very much